# Flask import static resources

Tags: flask, flask-assets

**The problem:** I get a 404 when I access static resources from any route other than `'/'`.

I have an image called `volume.png` in my `static` folder in my `Flask` application. When I route my main page to `'/'` using `@app.route('/')` it finds the image fine, and I can display the image when I hit `localhost:5000/static/images/volume.png`. But when I use any other link, for example, `'/s'`, it says it can't find the image in `s/static/images/volume.png`. Even when I create an `s` directory and copy the `static` directory to it, I get a `404` when I type `localhost:5000/s/static/images/volume.png`. I've considered using `Flask-Assets`, but there doesn't appear to be much documentation or examples. What's a good way to make sure my routes have access to the static resources?

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:5000/s/../static/images/volume.png`? it sounds like to me that you're passing a relative path to your route rather then starting from your project root and traversing from there.

Comment: Nope, it redirects immediately to `localhost:5000/s/static/images/volume.png` and gives a `404`.

Comment: Do you have to stay on this path? would it be possible to redirect to / ?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. Why isn't it simple to use different routes and access static resources?

Comment: Well, there are one ways you can make this simple but it requires a little bit of hard coding. One solution is to have a `/<path:resource>` variable to the end of everyone one of your URL routes (or at least, to every route you car about).

So the s route would turn into `'/s/<path:resource>'` and you'd follow the resource path to your static resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the path to your image in your HTML (or CSS):

```
<!-- This will break in the way you describe -->
<img src="static/images/volume.png" />

<!-- This will not -->
<img src="/static/images/volume.png" />

<!-- Nor will this (assuming you are using a Jinja template) -->
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/volume.png') }}" />
```

The reason for this is because of the way that user-agents are required to resolve relative paths for URIs (see [section 5.1 of RFC 3968 for the details](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)).

Using `static/images/volume.png` results in the following path at `/`:

```
scheme://host.name/static/images/volume.png
```

and the following at `/s`:

```
scheme://host.name/s/static/images/volume.png
```

as you have discovered.  By ensuring that you provide an absolute `path` component (at the very least) for your resources, you ensure that the browser will merge your provided path with only `scheme` and `host.name`, rather than with `scheme`, `host.name` and `path`.